# In opengl es 2, is there a way to prevent interpolation of varyings

Tags: opengl-es

In other words, emulating the old opengl flat shading model, so you could for example have a line strip where each segment is a distinct color rather than an interpolation of color across the segment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass non interpolated data OpenGL ES (GLSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700134/how-to-pass-non-interpolated-data-opengl-es-glsl)

Answer (score 4):

Not directly. GLSL for Desktop has the flat keyword, but GLSL ES doesn't have it (it's reserved). A trick to emulate this behaviour is to assign the same color at each vertex in a triangle (or in a segment), so the interpolation is between the same value.

Comment: right, but then you can't use strips...better than nothing though

Comment: 'Emulate'??? No. You abuse the word!

The behaviour is NOT the same as taking a flat variable from a provoking vertex!

As RobbieC pointed out, it means waving a sad goodbye to nice, efficient tri strips. To pass per-face data through the pipeline will force vertex duplication, just to have distinct variables each time a vertex is reused for a new tri.

I'm sure RobbieC is aware of this 'trick' anyway; it's the way that tutorials tend to do things, even when 'flat' IS available.

I think he was hoping to write better code than is found in those tutorials -- as was I