# How to pass non interpolated data OpenGL ES (GLSL)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to pass simple FLOAT value from vertex to fragment shader. How can I pass it "as is" without interpolation? 
On desktop I could use flat varying to disable interpolation, is there something similar in openGL es or the only way is through texture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In opengl es 2, is there a way to prevent interpolation of varyings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409516/in-opengl-es-2-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-interpolation-of-varyings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GLSL ES does currently not support the `flat` keyword, so the only way is to use the same float value in all the triangle vertices.

The same answer was given here:
[In opengl es 2, is there a way to prevent interpolation of varyings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409516/in-opengl-es-2-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-interpolation-of-varyings)

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support the `flat` keyword. However OpenGL ES 3.0 does.

Answer (score 0):

GLSL ES 2.0 does not support the `flat` [interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers), just as it does not support integral vertex shader output variables.
Compare [OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) and [OpenGL ES 3.0. Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf).